# Use search_criteria to filter custom extension collection in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection, search-criteria

I generated a custom extension with a custom model collection from [mage2gen](http://mage2gen.com) , is it possible to implement the `search_criteria` like when you retrieve product using rest api? what i know is the product model will use `getList` function to filter collection by `search_criteria`:

```
$this->procudtRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
```

if i have a post input with parameter `search_criteria` like this:

```
'searchCriteria' => [
  'page_size'=> 3,
  'current_page'=> 15,
  'filterGroups' => [
    0 => [
      'filters' => [
         0 => [
           'field' => 'location',
           'value' => '%as%',
           'condition_type' => 'like'
         ]
    1 => [
      'filters' => [
         0 => [
           'field' => 'distance',
           'value' => '100',
           'condition_type' => 'lt'
         ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

Is it possible to just implemented it like this:

```
public function __construct(
 /Namespace/Module/Model/CollectionFactory $collection
){
 $this->collection = $collection;
}

public function execute(){
 $searchCriteria = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue('searchCriteria');
 $collections = $this->collection->create()->getList($searchCriteria);
 return $collections;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one of possible way to implement searchCriteria.

```
    $requestParams = $this->_request->getParams();
    foreach($requestParams as $key => $value){
        if($key == "location"){
            $filters[] = $this->_filterBuilder->setField($key)->setConditionType("like")->setValue($value)->create();    
        }
        elseif($key == "distance"){
            $filters[] = $this->_filterBuilder->setField($key)->setConditionType("lt")->setValue($value)->create(); 
        }
    }

    if(count($filters) > 0){


        foreach($filters as $filterData){
            $filterGroup[] =  $this->_filterGroupBuilder->addFilter($filterData)->create();
        }          

        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setFilterGroups($filterGroup)->create();
        $collections = $this->collection->create()->getList($searchCriteria);
        return $collections;
    }
```